# Pagination query not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have a problem in my pagination. My scenario is I'll just the filters then click search. Then the result will show the output. But when I click on page 2 it returns to the query for all not the query that is filtered.

> Controller

```
<?php //CONTROLLER
function maintenance(){

        if($this->session->userdata('l@ginUs3r')) {

            $session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('l@ginUs3r');
            $data['u_id'] = $session_data['u_id'];
            $data['u_uname'] = $session_data['u_uname'];
            $data['u_pword'] = $session_data['u_pword'];
            $data['u_role'] = $session_data['u_role'];
            $data['is_active'] = $session_data['is_active']; 

            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "personnel/maintenance/";
            $config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf();
            $config["per_page"] = 10;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $data['prf'] = $this -> Main -> select_prf($config['per_page'], $page);
            $data["prf_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

                if(isset($_POST['search']))
                    {
                            if($_POST['division'] != "" && $_POST['group'] != "" && $_POST['department'] != "" && $_POST['position'] != "" )
                            {
                                if($_POST['date_rec'] != "" && $_POST['date_upto'] != "")
                                {
                                    $where = "prf_div = '".$_POST['division']."' AND prf_group = '".$_POST['group']."' AND prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' AND prf_dept = '".$_POST['department']."' AND prf_position = '".$_POST['position']."' AND prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' AND prf_daterec BETWEEN '".$_POST['date_rec']."' AND '".$_POST['date_upto']."' ";
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    $where = "prf_div = '".$_POST['division']."' AND prf_group = '".$_POST['group']."' AND prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' AND prf_dept = '".$_POST['department']."' AND prf_position = '".$_POST['position']."' AND prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' ";
                                }

                            }
                            //NEXT IF FOR SEARCH
                            if($_POST['division'] == "" && $_POST['group'] == "" && $_POST['department'] == "" && $_POST['position'] == "" )
                            {
                                if($_POST['date_rec'] != "" && $_POST['date_upto'] != "")
                                {
                                    $where = "prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' AND prf_daterec BETWEEN '".$_POST['date_rec']."' AND '".$_POST['date_upto']."' ";
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    $where = "prf_status = '".$_POST['prf_status']."' ";

                                }

                            }
                                    $_SESSION['page_list'] = $where;

                                    $config = array();
                                    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "personnel/maintenance/";
                                    $config["total_rows"] = $this -> Main -> count_prf_where($_SESSION['page_list']);
                                    $config["per_page"] = 10;
                                    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
                                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                                    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
                                    $data["prf"] = $this -> Main -> fetch_prf($_SESSION['page_list'], $config["per_page"], $page);
                                    $data["prf_links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                    }
            $this -> load -> view('templates/header', $data);
            $this -> load -> view('pages/maintenance', $data);


$this -> load -> view('templates/footer');

            } else {

                $this -> load -> view('templates/lheader');
                $this -> load -> view('pages/login');
                $this -> load -> view('templates/footer');

            }

        }
  ?>
```

> View

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-search-cust1 pull-right" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>personnel/add_prf'"><span class="icon-file"></span></button>

<button type="button" name="back" class="btn btn-success btn-search-cust pull-right" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>personnel/home'"> <span class="icon-home"></span> </button>

<?php $this -> load -> view('templates/maintenance-navbar'); ?>

<article class="grid_12 panel">

    <div class=""><span class=""> </span><label class="listnames">Filter</label></div>

    <div class="tab-field">

    <form method="POST" action="<?=base_url()?>personnel/maintenance">

        <label class="listnames">Division</label>

        <select class="cust_fields" name="division">

            <option value="">--Select--</option>

            <?php if(!$ddl2){ ?>

                <option value=""><?="NO DATA"?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <?php foreach($ddl2 as $row){ ?>

                <option value="<?=$row['d_id']?>"><?=$row['d_divname']?></option>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>


        <label class="listnames">Group</label>

        <select class="cust_fields" name="group">

            <option value="">--Select--</option>

            <?php if(!$ddl2){ ?>

                <option value=""><?="NO DATA"?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <?php foreach($ddl1 as $row){ ?>

                <option value="<?=$row['g_id']?>"><?=$row['g_name']?></option>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>

        <label class="listnames">PRF Status<!--FORMERLY ROLE --></label>

        <select name="prf_status" id="roles" class="cust_fields">

            <option value="Outstanding">Outstanding</option>
            <option value ="Served">Served</option>

        </select>

        <br>

        <label class="listnames">Department</label>

        <select name="department" id="roles" class="cust_fields">

            <option value="">--Select--</option>

            <?php if(!$ddl3){ ?>

                <option value=""><?="NO DATA"?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <?php foreach($ddl3 as $row){ ?>

                <option value="<?=$row['dept_id']?>"><?=$row['dept_name']?></option>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>

        <label class="listnames">Position</label>

        <select name="position" id="roles" class="cust_fields">

            <option value="">--Select--</option>

            <?php if(!$ddl5){ ?>

                <option value=""><?="NO DATA"?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <?php foreach($ddl5 as $row){ ?>

                <option value="<?=$row['r_id']?>"><?=$row['r_rank']?></option>

                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>

        </select>

        <label class="listnames">Date Received</label>

        <input type="date" name="date_rec" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="fromdate" autocomplete="off"  style="height: 24px; width: 128px;">

        <label class="listnames" style = "width: 15px;">To</label>

        <input type="date" name="date_upto" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="fromdate" autocomplete="off"  style="height: 24px; width: 128px;">

        <button type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-success cust_search"><span class="icon-search2"></span></button>

        <!-- <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"> -->

    </form>




    </div>

</article>


<table class="table">

        <tr class="thead1" style = "background: #D6C9A4;">


            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><th >Division</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Group</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Department</th></div></div>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><th >Position</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Rank</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Ex. No. of Personnel</th></div></div>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><th >No. of Req. Personnel</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >No. of Served Personnel</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Reason for PRF</th></div></div>
          </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row"><div class="col-md-3"><th >Date Received</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Date Served</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >Age of PRF</th></div><div class="col-md-3"><th >PRF Status</th></div></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        </tr>
        <?php 

        if(!$prf)
        {

        ?>
            <h3 class="tab-field">No Data</h3>
        <?php

        }
        $x = 1;
        foreach($prf as $row){ 
            $id = $row['prf_id'];
            $now = time();
            $your_date = strtotime($row['prf_daterec']);
            $datediff = $now - $your_date;
            $age = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
            $date_rec = substr($row['prf_daterec'], 0, -13);
            $date_serv = substr($row['prf_dateserv'], 0, -13);

        ?>
        <tr id="active" onclick="window.location.href='<?=base_url()?>personnel/prf_info/<?=$id?>'">

            <td><?=strtoupper($row['d_divname'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['g_name'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['dept_name'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['prf_position'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['r_rank'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['prf_ex_no_personnel'])?></td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['prf_no_req_personnel'])?></td>
            <td>Served Personnel</td>
            <td><?=strtoupper($row['prf_reason'])?></td>
            <td><?=$date_rec?></td>
            <td><?=$date_serv?></td>
            <td><?=$age?> Days</td>
            <td><?=$row['prf_status']?></td>

        </tr>               

        <?php } ?>

    </table>

    <div class="pagination-align"><?=$prf_links?></div>
```

Comment: What about storing the filters in a session and use it if there is not a $_post action?

Comment: I'll try to do that. I'll update as soon as I acomplish it.

Comment: Are you passing the page number along with url  personnel/maintenance/page/1 if not try to pass it, catch the param and create query accordingly and return the data along with page number to the view. Create an pagination like we always do in core PHP.